# Laravel Eloquent saveMany does not accept second attribute

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, array-map

As I think it is typically as the [documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) I have tried to use `saveMany` regarding its parameters as Model objects.

I have a model named `Set` and it `hasMany` `Equipment` so, from the from that creates a set I submit many fields of `Equipment` in-order to be saved as the following:

```
//Store method of SetController
$set = new Set();
        $set->title = request('title');
        $set->eqtype_id = request('eqtype');
        $set->product_id = request('product');
        $set->parts_count = request('parts_count');
        $eq = request('equipments');
        $set->equipments()->saveMany(array_map(function($n){return new \App\Equipment(['title' => $n, 'eqtype_id' => request('eqtype')]);}, $eq));
        $set->save();
```

However, I always get the error message about that `eqtype_id` does not has a default value:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'eqtype_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `equipments` (`title`, `set_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (A-1, , 2017-03-18 12:07:30,
>   2017-03-18 12:07:30))

I thought that, may be, `request('eqtype')` is not accessible from the `array_map` callback, so I replaced it with a fixed number as follows:

```
$set->equipments()->saveMany(array_map(function($n){return new \App\Equipment(['title' => $n, 'eqtype_id' => 1]);}, $eq));
```

But also the error is same, it seems like a problem with either `saveMany` or `array_map`. I don't know how to fix this issue!

#### Notice

The model `Equipment` is related with the both model `Set` and `Eqytpe` as follows:

```
    //Equipment model
       <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * App\Equipment
 *
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */
class Equipment extends Model
{
    public $table = "equipments";
    protected  $fillable = ['title'];
    public function set()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Set::class);
    }

    public function eqtype()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Eqtype::class);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `eqtype_id` in the `INSERT` statement in the query?

Comment: @JaredFarrish That is the core of my question! why `eqtype_id` is not there althoug I entered it in `array_map`?!

Comment: @JaredFarrish Checkout the update of the question. I inclided it.

Comment: I don't see a `$this->eqtype_id` column defined, only the `eqtype()` method; what would passing that array into the constructor for Equipment do?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Oh I have got it, in the model defination I have forgot to set `eqtype_id` as `fillable`!

Comment: I would say it looks like something having to do with how you instantiate your Equipment objects when you pass in data.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of had the same problem and this is what I did to fix it:

I had a One to Many relationship between a Product and Image and I wanted on a product creation add all the images related to it

```php
// Create post
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $newProduct = Product::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'price' => $request->price,
        'stock_items' => $request->stock_items,
    ]);


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->image_path); $i++) {
        $newProduct->image()->saveMany([

            new Image(['image_path' => $request->image_path[$i]])

        ]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget the relationship functions & to create multiple input with the same name :  name='image_path[]'